# Java synchronization help request

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm implementing a network thread manager for my application. I have created a JUnit test, which rapidly requests and releases a network thread index by invoking the following two methods:

```
protected static final List <Integer> currThreads          = new ArrayList <Integer>();
protected static int                  maxThreads           = 5;
protected static int                  lastGrantedId        = 0;

public static synchronized int reqNewThread(){
    if (currThreads.size() >= maxThreads) return -1;
    ++lastGrantedId;
    currThreads.add(lastGrantedId);
    return lastGrantedId;
}

public static void threadFinished(final int threadId) throws InternalError{
    if (threadId == -1) return;
    synchronized (currThreads) {
        boolean works = currThreads.remove(Integer.valueOf(threadId));
        assert works : ("threadId: " + threadId);
    }
}
```

After thread finishes their work, `currThreads` is not empty, but `reqNewThread` and `threadFinished` have the same invocation count and `remove()` always yield `true`. If I synchronize the whole `threadFinished` method, it works fine. Question is - why? The only used global variable is already synchronized, isn't it?

JUnit4 testing code:

```
final int iters = 15;
final Runnable getAndFree = new GetAndFree(iters);
final int sz = 15;
final Thread[] t = new Thread[sz];
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    t[i] = new Thread(getAndFree);
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    t[i].start();
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    t[i].join();
assertEquals(0, currThreads.size());
```

Tester thread source:

```
private class GetAndFree implements Runnable {
    int iters;

    public GetAndFree(int iters){
        this.iters = iters;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            int id = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
                while ((id = reqNewThread()) == -1) {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                };
                System.out.println("Strarted: " + id);
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 10));
                threadFinished(id);
                System.out.println("Finished: " + id);
            } // for
        } catch(final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only used global variable is already synchronized, isn't it?

No.

The first method is synchronizing on the `Class` object for the method's enclosing class.

The second method is synchronizing on the `currThreads` object.

Change the first method to the following, and it should fix the synchronization issue with respect to these two methods.

```
public static int reqNewThread(){
    synchronize(currThread) {
        if (currThreads.size() >= maxThreads) return -1;
        ++lastGrantedId;
        currThreads.add(lastGrantedId);
        return lastGrantedId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks :) I'm an idiot. I'l accept your answer as soon as I can.